# Windows Chromium Build Errors: No such file or directory 2000 times

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, chromium

I am building the Chromium source code on a Windows 7 x64 computer. I downloaded the source using the build instructions provided and set up the environment as told by the instruction pages. I can open the solution in VS2010Pro successfully (albeit taking a while), and I can edit the code.

When I try to build the solution, I get thousands of errors (last time, 2703). The first batch are that Cmd.exe exited with error code 1; there are about 20 of those. Then most of the rest complain that C++ header files are not found by the compiler. Here are a few randomly selected from throughout the long error list.

Error 138: error C1083: **Cannot open include file: 'EventInterfaces.h': No such file or directory**    D:\Chromium\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\core\dom\EventNames.h in project  webcore_rendering

Error 1952: error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'grit/ui_resources.h': No such file or directory D:\Chromium\src\chrome\browser\ui\chrome_style.cc in project browser_ui

Error 2482: error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'grit/generated_resources.h': No such file or directory  D:\Chromium\src\chrome\browser\printing\print_dialog_cloud.cc in project browser

Now, not all projects fail to build. Last time, 526 projects succeeded and **only 199 failed.** Having followed the instructions word by word, and tried a clean download twice, I really don't see what could be wrong.

EDIT: Still fails, but looking through the Output I noticed the cause of the Cmd.exe errors

```
28>------ Build started: Project: convert_dict, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
27>  Traceback (most recent call last):
27>    File "../tools/grit/grit/format/repack.py", line 27, in <module>
27>      main(sys.argv)
27>    File "../tools/grit/grit/format/repack.py", line 24, in main
27>      grit.format.data_pack.RePack(argv[1], argv[2:])
27>    File "../tools/grit/grit/format\../..\grit\format\data_pack.py", line 120, in RePack
27>      new_content = ReadDataPack(filename)
27>    File "../tools/grit/grit/format\../..\grit\format\data_pack.py", line 54, in ReadDataPack
27>      data = util.ReadFile(input_file, util.BINARY)
27>    File "../tools/grit/grit/format\../..\grit\util.py", line 207, in ReadFile
27>      with open(filename, mode) as f:
27>  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/Chromium/src/build/Debug/obj/global_intermediate/content/content_resources.pak'
27>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
```

Comment: if youre still facing these problems ask in chromium-dev group for all build related queries https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-dev

fyi. using ninja is better as its relatively faster also.